# XML: How to place a restriction to a base simple element which was extended with attributes?

Tags: validation, xsd, restriction

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Child name="MyType" compareMode="EQ">Child1</Child>
</Root>
```

Usually in order to verify such an xml one would use the following xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Child">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="compareMode" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I want to limit values of a *Child* element and allow only the following: *Child1*, *Child2* and *Child3*.

I know that usually restriction may be specified with the following schema:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="Child1"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="Child2"/>
  <xs:enumeration value="Child3"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

Which restriction is correct in the first case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

[Having both an attribute and a restriction on an element in xml schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336061/having-both-an-attribute-and-a-restriction-on-an-element-in-xml-schema)

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong, because I didn't test my answer. I edited it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="ChildContent">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Child1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Child2"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Child3"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:complexType name="Child">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="ChildContent">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="compareMode" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>     
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Child" type="Child" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

or with restriction:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="Child">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                <xs:attribute name="compareMode" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Child">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:restriction base="Child">
                                <xs:enumeration value="Child1"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="Child2"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="Child3"/>
                            </xs:restriction>     
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

After hours spent with google: You cannot do this without named types.

Comment: @inf3mo thanks for the answer! Unfortunately when I apply your configuration I see the following error: *s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_MetaInfoRootChild' is invalid. Element 'simpleContent' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.*. Which source of information had you used in order to construct such xml schema? Could you please drop a link?

Comment: +1, this looks to be correct, in fact, I have used the same solution which was proposed by Tomasz. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yepp, I saw too late, that Tomasz wrote the same solution, so I edited again, and added another solution under the "or with restriction" part.