# Adding both restriction and attribute(s) to complexType

Tags: xml, xsd, structure

To a simple element with `type="xs:int"` I would like to add both a restriction and a number of attributes. However, the only way I have seen it done is in a two-step approach:

1. Declare a named (global) type and put all the restrictions in the named type
2. Refer to the named type in the `base` of an `<xs:extension>` and add the attributes to the extension node.

It could be nice if I could avoid declaring a global named type as the schema is generated dynamically and it would be a lot cleaner to specify all restrictions locally. E.g. like this:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:int">
      <xs:minInclusive>2</xs:minInclusive>
      <xs:attribute name="myAttribute" type="xs:boolean" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

or in case of a string-type:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleContent>
    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration Value="FOO" />
      <xs:enumeration Value="BAR" />
      <xs:enumeration Value="BAZ" />
      <xs:attribute name="myAttribute" type="xs:boolean" />
    </xs:extension>
  </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Unfortunately, it does not seem that a "combined" declaration like this is allowed.

Comment: Have to admit I'm still a bit confused about basis on which answers are accepted on SO :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, please review: [Having both an attribute and a restriction on an element in xml schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336061/having-both-an-attribute-and-a-restriction-on-an-element-in-xml-schema) answer thou.

Comment: I saw the post but didn't thought it matched my problem. Giving it a closer look, I can see that it actually does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do it. The way you do it currently (with separate type) is the way to go. Such requests were raised [before](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/604681-how-use-restrictions-extensions-xsd-simultanously) (though maybe not in SO).